# Can a metric subspace be completely covered by balls after a finite number of steps?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ me a metric space with distance $d$ and $A$ be a subspace of $X$.

Let $B_\varepsilon(x)$ be the open ball centered in $x$ with radius $\varepsilon$, i.e. $\{y\in X\mid d(x,y) < \varepsilon\}$.

Let $B_\varepsilon(S) = \displaystyle\bigcup_{x\in S} B_\varepsilon(x)$

Let $S_0:=\{x_i\}_{i\in I_0}$ be a set of points such that:

> $x_i\in A\quad \forall i\in I_0$.
>
> $B_\varepsilon(x_i)\cap B_\varepsilon(x_j) = \emptyset\quad \forall i\neq j$
>
> If $x\in A\setminus S_0$ then $\exists i\in I_0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x)\cap B_\varepsilon(x_i) \neq \emptyset$

(In other words, I'm taking a maximal set of points of $A$ so that any two are separated by $2\varepsilon$ or more)

At this point if $A\setminus B_\varepsilon(S_0) \neq \emptyset$ then we create:

$S_1:=\{x_i\}_{i\in I_1}$ such that:

> $x_i\in A\quad \forall i\in I_1$.
>
> $B_\varepsilon(x_i)\cap B_\varepsilon(x_j) = \emptyset\quad \forall i\neq j$
>
> If $x\in A\setminus(S_0\cup S_1)$ then $\exists i\in I_1$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x)\cap B_\varepsilon(x_i) \neq \emptyset$

(In other words, I'm taking a maximal set of points of $A\setminus B_\varepsilon(S_0)$ so that any two are separated by $2\varepsilon$ or more)

At this point, if $A\setminus B_\varepsilon(S_0\cup S_1)\neq \emptyset$ then we create $S_2$ in a similar way. If $B_\varepsilon(S_0\cup S_1\cup S_2)$ does not cover $A$ we construct $S_3$ and so forth.

The questions are:

Given $\varepsilon > 0$ can we ensure that this process will finish after a finite amount of steps?

If so, is there an upper bound of said ampunt of steps?

---

A small example. Consider $X = A = \mathbb{R}$ with the euclidean distance.

Consider any $\varepsilon > 0$. Then let $k$ be the smallest integer such that $k\varepsilon \geq 1$. This means that $S_0$ has a countable amount of points.

We can order the points of $S_0$ acording to the usual total order $\leq$ of $\mathbb{R}$. In this case, $2\varepsilon < d(x_n,x_{n+1}) < 4\varepsilon$. In other words, the diameter of any conex subset of $\mathbb{R}\setminus B_\varepsilon (S_0)$ is less than $2\varepsilon$ (otherwise we could fit another ball in there)

In the next iteration we create $S_1 = \{y_i\}$ where $x_n < y_n < x_{n+1}$ and $\varepsilon < d(x_n,y_n) < 3\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon < d(y_n,x_{n+1}) < 3\varepsilon$. In other words,  the diameter of any conex subset of $\mathbb{R}\setminus B_\varepsilon (S_0\cup S_1)$ is less than $\varepsilon$.

This means that when we put the points of $S_2$ in said connex subsets (one in each) then $\mathbb{R}\setminus B(S_0\cup S_1\cup S_2) = \emptyset$.

Thus three steps are sufficient to cover $\mathbb{R}$ with balls of any radius $\varepsilon$.

Comment: I may have missed something: are we assured that $A$ has finite diameter?

Comment: @David: Even if $A$ has finite diameter, it need not be totally bounded, so $S_0$ may be infinite.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I was assuming each ball is a step, so infinite $S_0$ means an infinite number of steps. I suppose if you count construction of an infinite number of balls as "one step" then the diameter of $A$ doesn't matter in the way I thought it might.

Comment: @David: The diameter of $A$ doesn’t matter at all: if $d$ is a metric on $A$, $\rho(x,y)=\min\{d(x,y),1\}$ is an equivalent metric with respect to which $A$ has diameter $1$, and for any $\epsilon\le 1$ it may take infinitely many open $\epsilon$-balls to cover $A$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So finite diameter of $A$ is not _sufficient_ to ensure a covering with finitely many $\epsilon$-balls; but what I had in mind was I thought it was _necessary_. Just out of curiosity, was that wrong?

Comment: @David: Yes, it’s necessary; that follows from the triangle inequality.

Comment: it seems to me when you say "If $x\notin S_0$" you mean "If $x\in A\setminus S_0$". It also seems to me that if you take $S_1=\emptyset$, then your defining condition (third line) is satisfied anyway. I feel your definition of $S_1$ may not express what you meant. Perhaps define $S_1$ by  $x\in A\setminus S_0$, $B_\varepsilon(x_i)\cap B_\varepsilon(x_j)=\emptyset$ if $i,j\in I_1$, and if $x\in A\setminus(S_1\cup S_0)$ then $\exists i\in I_1$ (rather than $i\in I_0\cup I_1$ ) such that  $B_\varepsilon(x)\cap B_\varepsilon(x_i)\not=\emptyset$ ?

Comment: @DavidK We are not assured that $A$ has a finite diameter. And yes, each step may involve an infinite amount of balls. Also the condition that $A$ has a finite diameter is not necessary: in the worst-case scenario, $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual euclidean distance) can be covered after three steps.

Comment: @Mirko Yes, that works better! Thanks

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Check the proof tha $\mathbb{R}$ can be covered after a finite amount of steps even though it has an infinite diameter. I've added it at the end of the question.

Comment: @DarthGeek The "necessary" condition I cited had to do with whether the covering can be done with a finite number of balls. As I already noted, if you use a countably infinite number of balls in one step than this condition doesn't matter.

Comment: the following might be a related paper, though not directly (I don't think it answers the above question, but it is about the collection of $\varepsilon$ balls, considering suitable equivalent metrics) http://www.auburn.edu/~gruengf/papers/eballs4.pdf also the official publication at http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/journal/01668641/124 and http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864101002516

Comment: @DarthGeek Since the tag "covering spaces" isn't about open covers in topology, but about [covering spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space) in algebraic topology, I have removed the tag from the question.

Answer (score 1):

For a metric space $(A,d)$ and $\varepsilon>0$ by $DG(A,d,\varepsilon)$ I denote the smallest number $N$ of steps needed to cover the $A$ for *any* realization of your (non-deterministic) algorithm and $\infty$, if there is no such $N$.

*Remark*. This definition can be naturally generalized to $DG(A,\mathcal U, U)$, where $(A,\mathcal U)$ is a uniform space and $U\in\mathcal U$ is an entourage.

**Proposition 1**. Let $(A,d)$ be the space $\Bbb R^n$  endowed with the standard metric and $\varepsilon>0$. Then $DG(A,d,\varepsilon)\le 5^n+1$.

*Proof*. Assume that after $N$ steps of the algorithm a point $x\in A$ left uncovered. Let $0\le i\le N-1$. By the maximality of the set $S_i$ there exists a point $x_i\in S_i$ such that $d(x, x_i)<2\varepsilon$. Therefore $B_{\varepsilon/2}(x_i)\subset B_{5\varepsilon/2}(x)$. From the other hand, the construction of the sets $S_i$ implies that the sets $B_{\varepsilon/2}(x_i)$ and $B_{\varepsilon/2}(x_j)$ are disjoint provided $i\ne j$. Since a ball with radius $5\varepsilon/2$ can cover at most $5^n$ mutually disjoint balls with radius $\varepsilon/2$, $N\le 5^n$.

*Remark.* For small $n$ better upper bounds can be obtained from circle or sphere packing bounds. For instance, current results (see [Bol] or [Fri]) suggest a bound $DG(\Bbb R^2,d,\varepsilon)\le 20$

*Remark*. I expect that Proposition 1 can be generalized to any metric $d$ on $\Bbb R^n$ generated by a norm.

*Conjecture 1*. Let $(A, d)$ be the space $\ell^2$ endowed with the standard metric. Then $DG(A,d,1)=\infty$.

PS. Now I'm going to pose your questions at Monday at our seminar "[Topology & Applications](http://prima.lnu.edu.ua/faculty/mechmat/Departments/Topology/index.html)", because they are similar to asymptotic (covering) dimension of metric space (especially, of macrofractals), which is investigated by my master [Taras Banakh](http://prima.lnu.edu.ua/faculty/mechmat/Departments/Topology/bancv.html) and his teacher [Michael Zarichnyi](http://prima.lnu.edu.ua/faculty/mechmat/Departments/Topology/zarichnyi.html).

*References for circle or sphere packing bounds*

[Bol] Dave Boll. *[Optimal Packing Of Circles And Spheres](http://www.frii.com/%7Edboll/packing.html)*.

[Fri] Erich Friedman. *[Packing center Circles in Circles](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/cirincir/)*.

[Pet] Ivars Peterson. *[Pennies in a Tray](http://www.maa.org/mathland/mathland_11_25.html)*.